# How do I create a ServiceReplicatorListener using the latest service fabric SDK 2.5.216?

Tags: service, sdk, service-fabric-stateful

I've recently upgrade our Service Fabric SDK from 2.4.145 to 2.5.216 however this has broken everything (no **IService** and no **CreateServiceRemotingListener** on the **StatefulService** base class). Previously you would create service replica listeners like so:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new[]
               {
                   new ServiceReplicaListener(this.CreateServiceRemotingListener)
               };
    }
```

However, the new SDK 2.5.216 no longer has the **CreateServiceRemotingListener** method on the base class. The documentation still thinks you can do this but I've check the source in GitHub and there is definitely no **CreateServiceRemotingListener** on the base class!

My question is how do I create the replica listener and also how do I override the listener settings i.e. MaxConcurrentCalls etc.?

*Microsoft: please improve the service fabric docs and add some decent examples.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) method on IService, but Remoting functionality was moved to a separate [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting/) package.